# Guardar una Imagen en Blobstore de Appengine Programáticamente desde Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-datastore

Necesito guardar una imagen que ya tengo en formato `blob` (Google Cloud Datastore) en Blobstore de Google App Engine.

Revise la documentación y solo tienen un ejemplo de almacenamiento por medio de fron-end usando JSP, pero yo estoy trabajando con Google Cloud Endpoints por lo que todo lo hago en back-end, la necesidad del Blobstore es que solicitare un URL para poder ver la imagen almacenada por HTTP usando Google Image Api para Java.

¿Como puedo almacenar esta imagen en Blobstore por medio de mi back-end sin necesidad del front-end?

Answer (score 0):

La recomendación oficial es utilizar Cloud Storage por sobre Blobstore, da la impresión que en algún momento este será deprecado.

Si todavía necesitas usar blobstore puedes usar el API del mismo para recuperar objetos almacenados en Cloud Datastore.

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(
    "/gs/tuBucket/elArchivo");
```

con ese blobkey puedes persistirlo o preferentemente usarlo directamente desde el cloud Storage.